# Regresión lineal simple con JavaScript TensorFlow

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

Ando probando tensorflow en js, y la verdad que soy totalmente nuevo en el tema del ML, la cuestión es que ando haciendo un ejemplo de regresión lineal simple muy basica pero los resultados que me devuelve no son para nada los que me debería de devolver, el resultado es 37 para cuando `x=20`, pero me devuelve valores totalmente aleatorios, basicamente he usado en ejemplo que dan en su pagina oficial pero cambiado los tensores, haber si alguien podría aclararme un poco el tema, gracias de antemano

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.11.2"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

//X entradas
//Y salidas deseadas  

 const xs = tf.tensor([2,3,5,7,9,10], [6,1]);


 const ys = tf.tensor([1,3,7,11,15,17], [6,1]);

 const model = tf.sequential();



//model regresion lineal simple, solo 1 variable dependiente (y) y 1 independiente (x) 


 model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));


 // Preparar entreno


 model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});

//Entrenamiento, cuanto mayor sea el numero mas tiempo tardara pero mas preciso sera


 model.fit(xs,ys,{epochs: 20});

 model.predict(tf.tensor([20],[1,1])).print();

</script>
```